# VSC PS performance

Tags: performance, powershell, visual-studio-code

With PS ISE still being indicated as being deprecated and VSC being pushed in its stead, is anything being done about the performance of Powershell scripts in VSC particularly when debugging, which has never been great but is now laughable ?

I have seen other similar question(s) to the above.  Is there anywhere that developers can go to try and ask for the  resolution of such issues to be given a higher priority ?

Answer (score 0):

The only times I've experienced performance issues with VS Code were while having a laptop with tons of scanners and AVs installed (official company laptop).
They were scanning VS Code and all the changes non-stop and this caused performance issues. I contacted my security department in my company and requested to add VS Code files to the whitelist. That did it and problems never occurred again. I had the same issue with Windows Terminal btw.

**BUT** what you can do is create an issue in VSC's official GitHub repo: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode explaining your problem with VS Code. It'll be nice to include anything devs request, because maybe there is something in the code that is performance-heavy.

Based on your PS version (if it's > 6.0) you can post an issue here: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell

Comment: Thanks Grzegorz !
Indeed the 'laughable' end has just sped up, so am suspecting an 'infrastructure' resolution somewhere, without infrastructure not notifying us of issues, or such being otherwise noticeable to me. ( I'd gone to the level of reinstalling an older VSC (having just update to latest) to see if made a difference). So perhaps jumped the gun a bit; but was still struggling to find away of trying to get someone else's reported issue raised as priority or marking as 'me also', which is what drove me to raise this Q.